# pylint installed, but not found on macOS Catalina with zsh

Tags: python-3.x, zsh, macos-catalina, pylint

I installed installed python 3.8 as the default version of python on my mac with Catalina.
The terminal runs zsh and not bash.
I pip installed pylint with
`pip install pylint` and get a message that it's already installed.
When I run `which pylint`, It says that pylint is not found.

`pip show --files pylint` shows:

```
Files:
  ../../../bin/epylint
  ../../../bin/pylint
etc.
```

I've added `export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH` to both my .zshrc and .zprofile and restarted my terminal. But I still get the same message.

Comment: This may sound stupid, but can you make sure `$HOME/.local/bin/pylint` exists?

Comment: No stupid questions apparently: `/Users/mymac/.local/bin/pylint not found`
What I don't understand is how `pip show` then does find `../../../bin/pylint`

Comment: Okay, from the directory where you did `pip show`, do `cd ../../../bin`. That directory is the one you want to add to `$PATH`